# adding the arrow to dropdown pills for twitter bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got the twitter bootstrap dropdown buttons successfully working, but I have a tiny problem. The black navbar here:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns

It has a neat little arrow when the dropdown opens, right? Well, I'm using the pills right below and they don't have that arrow. It seems the arrow is only included when using the navbar, which I don't need.

Has anyone figured out a way to add the arrows to the pills? :(

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to the white arrow that points upward when a menu item is clicked, the style you're looking for is on line 3907 in bootstrap.css:

```
.navbar .dropdown-menu::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid white;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}
```

You can try copying this style and removing the `.navbar` portion of the style declaration and modify it to fit your code.

Comment: That is PERFECT! Thank you :) I simply created a copy, removed the .navbar and not it works!!!!

Comment: This works but the border around the arrow is not showing up. Any ideas what I should do?

Comment: @Anthony This is because you need to also include the ::before style, which actually creates the border around the arrow. :) See some other answers on this page. Frankly, this one accepted isn't the best.

Comment: Just an FYI regarding the above two comments: the arrow might not be showing up because it's white and the background (i.e., your dropdown menu and page) might also be white. Change `white` above to `black` or another color and it should be visible then.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a refinement to Jason Towne's answer.

This works correctly if the menu has been pulled to the right.

```
.dropdown-menu-arrow::before {
    border-bottom: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    left: 9px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
}

.dropdown-menu-arrow::after {
    border-bottom: 6px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
}

.btn-group.pull-right > .dropdown-menu-arrow::before {
    left: inherit;
    right: 9px;
}

.btn-group.pull-right > .dropdown-menu-arrow::after {
    left: inherit;
    right: 10px;
}
```

Here's an example of usage.

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle">
    Actions
    <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-arrow">
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what the pills are, but if you have bootstrap you add the arrows by simply putting this anywhere in your code.

```
<b class="caret"></b>
```

Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yeah, that's the downward arrow, I figured that one out, but the problem is the upwards arriv that looks like an inverted "v" out of the menu that then opens, towards the link above.

Comment: Those get created with ::before (which is css3) so depending on what browser you're using, it will or won't show up :/

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me

---

```
    //css
        .arrow-right > .dropdown-menu:after {
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        border-left: 6px solid transparent;
        border-right: 6px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
        position: absolute;
        top: -6px;
        right: 10px;
        }

        .arrow-left > .dropdown-menu:after {
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        border-left: 6px solid transparent;
        border-right: 6px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
        position: absolute;
        top: -6px;
        left: 10px;
        }

    // html

//for left side dropdown menu

    <div class="dropdown arrow-left">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    ...
    </ul>
    </div>


//for right side dropdown menu

    <div class="dropdown pull-right arrow-right">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
    Dropdown
    <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    ...
    </ul>
    </div>
```