# Adding arrow to bootstrap dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can figure out how to do this. This topic help me out: [adding the arrow to dropdown pills for twitter bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633463/adding-the-arrow-to-dropdown-pills-for-twitter-bootstrap)

By adding

```
.dropdown-menu::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid white;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}
```

I was able to get the arrow show. However, there is no border around the top of arrow so it just looks like a gap in the dropdown now. does anyone know how to add the border to the up arrow?

Answer (score 0):

Add a rule for border-top.  Something like

```
border-top: 8px solid white;
```

Comment: nope that does not work. Just puts a horizontal line across the top of the arrow

Comment: @Anthony Could you please share your markup and relevant css?  Without it we can only guess what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding following markup:

```
.savedsearchWrapper .dropdown-menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: 23px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}


.advancedSearchDropDown .dropdown-menu:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 17px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: '';
}
```

Those are bootstrap styles but the selector was too specific for my implementation.